# How to create an AWS service client object for a .NET Core desktop app

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-5, aws-sdk-net

I am coding an app in .NET 5.0 to run on the desktop. It will query AWS CloudWatch and download log entries.

I am using the following method to create the AWS service client that contains the query method. When the program enters the `CreateServiceClient()` method however, it hangs for a minute then returns directly to the method that calls my `GetLogs()` method, with no error.

```
using Amazon.CloudWatchLogs;
using Amazon.CloudWatchLogs.Model;
using Amazon.Extensions.NETCore.Setup;
.
.
.
public async Task<GetQueryResultsResponse> GetLogs()
{ 
       AWSOptions awsOptions = new AWSOptions { Profile = "myprofile" };
       IAmazonCloudWatchLogs logs = awsOptions.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonCloudWatchLogs>();
       .
       .
       .
```

I have a credentials file located at `C:\Users\Username\.aws\credentials` with the contents

```
[myprofile]
aws_access_key_id = <myid>
aws_secret_access_key = <mykey>
```

I have verified the credentials work with AWS CLI.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu are not using the latest .NET API. Here is an example that shows how to create an Amazon CloudWatch log group using [AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudWatchLogs/TCloudWatchLogsClient.html). The example was created using the AWS SDK for .NET version 3.7 and .NET Core 5.0.

You should be using [version 3.0 of the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html#about-this-version).

More examples here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/CloudWatchLogs

```
namespace CreateLogGroupExample
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Amazon.CloudWatchLogs;
    using Amazon.CloudWatchLogs.Model;

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows how to create an Amazon CloudWatch Logs log group. The example
    /// was created using the AWS SDK for .NET version 3.7 and .NET Core 5.0.
    /// </summary>
    public class CreateLogGroup
    {
        // snippet-start:[CloudWatchLogs.dotnetv3.CreateLogGroupExample]
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            // This client object will be associated with the same AWS Region
            // as the default user on this system. If you need to use a
            // different AWS Region, pass it as a parameter to the client
            // constructor.
            var client = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient();

            string logGroupName = "cloudwatchlogs-example-loggroup";

            var request = new CreateLogGroupRequest
            {
                LogGroupName = logGroupName,
            };

            var response = await client.CreateLogGroupAsync(request);

            if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Successfully create log group with ID: {logGroupName}.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not create log group.");
            }
        }

        // snippet-end:[CloudWatchLogs.dotnetv3.CreateLogGroupExample]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. When I run this I get the same behavior when instantiating the `AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient` object though. I filled in my log group and tried passing `RegionEndpoint` in the constructor. It's not finding my credentials file for some reason.

Comment: I will try this too and see if I can reproduce the issue

Comment: I ported the code over to a server running WinSvr2019 and it creates the client. I was trying to run it on a Svr2022 machine but not sure if the OS itself makes a difference.